# Инъекция, сюръекция, биекция

Tags: алгоритм, множества

Всем привет

вопрос касается не API и механизмов языка, а алгоритмов

вкратце формулировка у неё следующая: у нас есть два множества, между которыми есть отображение. Оно может быть инъективным и/или сюръективным. Нужно определить, возможно ли выделить из заданного множества связей подмножество, соответствующее биекции

если ближе к предметике, то первое множество - это актуальные значения, второе - ожидаемые. Порядок следования для обоих множеств значения не имеет. Для ожидаемых прописана операция, применив которую к актуальному мы получим булевское значение.
Например, actual="abc" operation="endsWith" expected="c" выдаст true: actual является прообразом expected. И вот у нас есть два таких множества одинакового размера, и нам нужно установить, отображаются ли они друг в друга биективно. Единственный рабочий вариант, который пока у меня есть - это брутфорсить. Но не хотелось бы. Можно ли установить по каким-либо критериям возможность выделения биективного отображения без перебора всех возможных вариантов? (Например, критерий "каждый элемент обоих множеств должен иметь минимум одну связь" необходим, но недостаточен, а проверять, мапится ли каждый прообраз из actual на свой образ в expected - это уже брутфорс). Может быть, есть какие-то теоремы, опираясь на которые, можно построить алгоритм? С удовольствием бы почитал что-нибудь по этой теме

Спасибо

Comment: какой размер множества? Так-то задача о паросочетании... Алгоритмы простые, сложность около линейной в случайных графах.

Comment: в основном ожидаются небольшие, не более 10 значений, но в принципе возможны и на 1000+

Comment: Чтобы отображение было биективно необходимо и достаточно, чтобы оно было инъективно (т.е. **разные** элементы исходного множества отображаются на **разные** элементы целевого множества) и сюръективно (т.е. **все** элементы целевого множества могут быть получены из исходного множества)

Comment: там в том и дело, что оно может быть как только сюръективно, так и только инъективно

Comment: Если, как Вы говорите, оба множества одного размера, то сюръективность автоматически будет означать и инъективность, иначе никак :)

Comment: На самом деле они могут быть разными, это я для упрощения привёл одинаковые. К тому же, при сюръекции разве будут задействованы именно все элементы исходного множества? Из определения я этого не увидел, по крайней мере

Comment: Ну, мы же сейчас говорим про случай, когда мощности множеств (пусть А и B) совпадают. Если каждый элемент B является образом по крайней мере одного одного элемента A, значит мощность прообраза B (назовем его С) должна быть не меньше мощности B: |C| >= |B|, при этом, с одной стороны С является подмножеством А, т. е. |C| <= |A|, а с другой, |A| = |B|. Отсюда следует, что |C| = |A|, а поскольку речь о конечных множествах, то C = A..

Comment: да, точно, для равнномощных множеств так и будет. Всем большое спасибо!